# Create a view with repeated combinations of certain columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I am trying to create a view that contains all combinations of data from 4 tables.
Here is the simplified layout of my tables:

```
users: 
user_id - a unique id 
name - name of the user 
role - the unique role of the user, which is one of the following

project: 
project_id - a unique id 
project_name - name of the project 

roles:
role - Unique role name.  Currently: (employee, manager, admin)

project_users: 
project_id - the project id from project table 
user_id - the user id from user table 
role - the role of the user associated with user_id
```

I basically want to create a view that contains all combinations of `project_id` and `role` and `user_id` regardless of whether there is a user of a certain role assigned to the project or not.

For example, if there are only 2 projects in the `project` table, and only 1 user is assigned to project 1 and no users are assigned to project 2, then the view should show something like this:

1. View - **project_roles**:

   - row 1: project_id = 1, role = employee, user_id = 1
   - row 2: project_id = 1, role = manager, user_id = null
   - row 3: project id = 1, role = admin, user_id = null
   - row 4: project_id = 2, role = employee, user_id = null
   - row 5: project_id = 2, role = manager, user_id = null
   - row 6: project_id = 2, role = admin, user_id = null

Basically I'm going to use this view to return projects that have no users of a particular role assigned to it.
For example, if I wanted to get a list of projects that don't have a manager assigned to it, I could just:

```
SELECT project_id FROM project_roles WHERE user_id IS NULL AND role='manager';
```

I can't seem to find a join query that would do this. So far I have something like the following:

```
CREATE VIEW project_roles AS
    SELECT
        pu.project_id,
        pu.user_id,
        r.role
    FROM
        project_users pu
        FULL OUTER JOIN role r ON pu.role = r.role;
```

However, it isn't giving me the desired view. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a `cross join` with a `left outer join`:

```
create view project_roles as
    select p.project_id, r.role, count(pu.user_id)
    from projects p cross join
         roles r left outer join
         project_users pu
         on pu.project_id = p.project_id and pu.role_id = r.role_id
    group by p.project_id, r.role;
```

The aggregation is needed to get the count.  Note that this will return `0` if no users are assigned to a particular project/role combination.  If you really want, you can convert this to a `NULL`.

EDIT:

I think this modification will work for the companies problem:

```
create view  project_roles as
    select p.project_id, r.role, count(pu.user_id)
    from projects p join
         roles r
         on p.company_id = r.company_id left outer join
         project_users pu
         on pu.project_id = p.project_id and pu.role_id = r.role_id
    group by p.project_id, r.role, r.company_id;
```

I'm not sure if you need `company_id` in the join to `project_users`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  That works!  However I just realized there's an extra factor I forgot to mention with my current database.  I have different companies that share the same database, so in the roles table there are actually duplicate roles with the same name, each one assigned to a different company ID.  Projects table also has company id column.

I realized that after trying the query example you gave, that it generated a huge view with millions of rows.  So now I'm trying to change the query so that it will also take the company id into account as well.  ><  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Thanks again Gordon~!

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I'm going to use this view to return projects that have no
>   users of a particular role assigned to it. For example, if I wanted to
>   get a list of projects that don't have a manager assigned to it, I could just:
>
> ```
> SELECT project_id FROM project_roles WHERE user_id IS NULL AND role='manager';
> ```

You don't need a (needlessly slow) view. Just use a query with a [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) anti-semi-join:

```
SELECT * FROM project
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM project_user WHERE role = 'manager');
```